# gparted does not resize/move

Tags: dual-boot, gparted

I wanted to use `gparted` to resize a Ubuntu `sda6` to dual boot with Kali but when i click on resize/move and try to resize nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a live CD? If not, try that. Also, it's a part of your extended partition, try clicking on extended and resize again.

Comment: can i use a usb ??

Comment: Yes, you can use a USB.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'nothing worked'? You cannot make any change (even visually) or you do that, but there is no effect on the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your picture, `sda6` shows a key icon, which means the partition is mounted.  Mounted partitions can't be operated on by `gparted`.  Back up your data - things can go wrong - then boot your system with a live USB - `gparted` is included on the Ubuntu live .isos - and perform your operations.

Comment: Mounted partitions *can* be grown -- they just can't be shrunk ( unless it is btrfs ).

Comment: primary is shaded, so I've chosen logical, is it OK, if not what should i do